# Collection subscription but no documents to client

Tags: meteor

This Meteor code gives full records to the client for one of the collections but the client browser gives:

`MyCol.findOne({});
undefined`

I also have a server side code which inserts documents into the collection and mongo terminal verifies documents exist.

Any idea why? Thanks

```js
//app.lib.js

MyCol = new Mongo.Collection('myCol');

//server
Meteor.publish('myCol', function() {
  return MyCol.find({});
});

//client main.js
Meteor.subscribe('myCol');

Template.checks.helpers({
  'values': function() {
    return MyCol.find({}); // no documents found, 
  }
});
```

Comment: Which version of Meteor are you running?

Comment: @IlanHasanov 1.3.3.1 and am doing the update to 1.3.4 now to see if that fixes it.

Comment: @IlanHasanov Yes. updating fixed it. thx for the hint